# Error while login customer into the authentication-popup frontend

Tags: customer, magento2.4, custom, login, authentication

Actually, I have installed the phone number login extension into Magento 2.4 downloaded it from GitHub, and added some new functionality as per the requirement after doing all functionality I faced an error in the authentication-popup login form check the below image.

[image]

I have checked all solutions related to this issue but have not gotten any solution, I have been stuck with this issue for 2 days.

And when I have to try to log in using this popup into the console also given an error like

[image]

For this functionality, I have override

Block:- vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account/AuthenticationPopup.php

Js:- vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/view/authentication-popup.js

This Two files I have to override into my custom module.

Anyone, please help me with this?

Thank You.